# Github pages deployment not properly implemented

Tags: html, css, reactjs, git, github

I tried to just run one of my repo to deploy using github but css and js contents not loading properly. here's the link of the repo : https://github.com/vipin10100001/agecalculator

now see the deployment of this : https://vipin10100001.github.io/agecalculator/

i tried to deploy a website but css and js elements not loading.

Comment: Hi, please do not rely only on links; put here a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You need to navigate to the specific HTML file, usually called `index.html` but in your case it is called `dob.html`. By adding the 'main page' file name to the end of your URL then you will see your code deployed on the web as expected.

In this case, navigate to: https://github.com/vipin10100001/agecalculator